# Dynamic Memory Allocation acting weird

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

I just found out that I can't write code like this

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
  int* a, b;
  int N;
  cin >> N;

  a = new int[N];
  b = new int[N];
}
```

But I can't understand why:

```cpp
  int*a, b;
```

is wrong, What is `b`'s type?

Comment: `b`s type is `int`, not `int*` as you expect. That is a good reason to not declare several variables on the same line. The correct way to do it on a single line is `int *a, *b;`

Comment: `b` is an `int`, not an `int*`. You could write `int* a, *b;` but for the sake of your and your team members' sanity, break it on separate lines: `int* a; int* b;`

Comment: And just as a visual cue. I write `int *a;`. It means exactly the same thing as `int* a;`, but putting the `*` next to the variable name emphasizes that it applies to the variable and not to the type.

Answer (score 3):

To put my comment as an answer:

> `b`s type is `int`, not `int*` as you expect. That is a good reason to not declare several variables on the same line. The correct way to do it on a single line is `int *a, *b;`

If you want to know more, the rules are listed [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/declarations). In your example `int` is in the `decl-specifier-seq` category and `*a, *b` is in the  `init-declarator-list` category.

The best is of course to initialize your variables as you declare them to avoid potential bugs:

```
int main() {
    int N = 0;
    std::cin >> N;
    int* a = new int[N];
    int* b = new int[N];

    //dont forget to delete
    delete[] a;
    delete[] b;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the first line:

```
  int* a, b;
```

It declared "a" as a pointer variable and "b" as an integer so you can write this in two ways:

```
  int* a, *b;
```

OR

```
  int* a;
  int* b;
```